# Merge and synonymize the tag [wireframing] into [wireframe]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, merge

The two tags are very similar and used interchangeably:

- [wireframe] currently has 177 questions.
- [wireframing] currently has 18 questions.

I think we could merge and synonymize them into [wireframe].

Comment: This has been completed.

Comment: Perfect, good work...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this tag merge.

A user likely isn't going to spend any time to figure out the nuanced distinction between

- the actual item produced ([wireframe](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireframe)) and
- the process of creating the item ([wireframing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireframing))

If someone said "I have a question about wireframes," and then proceeded to ask you about your process for creating them, you probably wouldn't look at them strange, because the process to create them is related to the topic of "wireframes".

Answer (score 0):

I had a look through the questions for both tags, and it would seem like currently there isn't much difference between the two.

However, I think there is some value to keeping the two tags separate, as "wireframes" should probably be used for questions relating to different elements of the actual physical or digital asset that is being produced, as opposed to "wireframing" which could be reserved for questions relating to various techniques and processes involved in creating a wireframe.

It is a valid question though, and I will probably keep an eye out on UXSE to ensure that questions are properly tagged as such, and update the tag description to reflect this.

Comment: Would you like to merge and synonomize these tags? Though a subtle semantic difference may exist, it's unlikely that users will consistently or predictably take any such subtleties into consideration. I think it's much neater for the tags to simply be synonyms of each other.

Comment: @maxathousand I was hoping that there would be a few more views, at the end of which if there's no real objections to this then I would merge and create synonyms for these tags. Perhaps I will continue to keep an eye on this but hopefully we can make the right decision about this soon :)

Comment: That's fair, though I wouldn't hold your breath for much input on meta ;) I've just seen several tag synonyms that seem to follow the same pattern (e.g. `sort` = `sorting`, `filter` = `filtering`). Proposed, we have `wireframe` = `wireframing` and `prototype` = `prototyping`. I agree with you that differences between the terms exist, but I question whether the subjects they reference are broad enough to warrant having two subtly distinct tags. Just my opinion